# error in the book "A first course in Machine Learning"?

Tags: references

I am reading the book "A first course in Machine learning". At page 74 when talking about the maximum likelihood solution, considering the data matrix `X` 2x2, he uses this expression

$z^TX^TXz = z_1^2\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i1}^2+2z_1z_2\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i1}x_{i2}+z_2^2\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i2}^2$

and then it says

> Because the first and last term must be positive, proving this expression is greater than zero is equivalent that their combined value is larger than the middle term:
>
> $z_1^2\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i1}^2++z_2^2\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i2}^2>2z_1z_2\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i1}x_{i2}$

and from that it makes some reasoning.

Should not be $z_1^2\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i1}^2++z_2^2\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i2}^2> - 2z_1z_2\sum_{i=1}^N x_{i1}x_{i2}$ or am I missing something?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: @AlejandroCelis Did you read the paragraph of the book?

Comment: yes.  These sign typos are not significant at the end as indeed $z^T X^T X z$ is positive definite for $z \neq 0$ since $X$ is a real symmetric matrix.  This is a linear algebra result that can be found in textbooks, search for quadratic forms.